# How to create a pop up in hybris backoffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to create a popup message in the Backoffice PCM. In particular, from within the editor area of a product. From the editor a user can click on the assortment view or compare view buttons on the side toolbar to change screens (redirect).

[image]

I want to give the user a popup to inform them that any changes will be lost.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I have tried to create my own widget and wiring my custom widget to the ootb *pcmbackoffice-toolbar* but have not been successful.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to display a simple popup via the ZK framework (the framework used by Backoffice). From the backoffice code you can open a popup like this:

```java
import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;

public void someMethod() {
  // do some actions...
  Messagebox.show("Some Messagetext", "Info", Messagebox.OK, Messagebox.INFO);
}
```